# Ultimate Numbers Only Textfield

Tags: javascript

does anybody know how to turn a textfield to allow user inputs of numbers only using javascript? I know this can be googled but solutions are all the same ex: (http://www.htmlcodetutorial.com/forms/index_famsupp_158.html). What I want is to filter any inputs not only coming from the keyboard but also but also from the mouse like doing copy & paste non-numeric values on the field. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: appart from all the answers given below, I would also give your inputs a type of number, at least, if you're coding your site in HTML5, which is the most future proof way to go. Input type=number will ensure that only numbers can be entered, in browsers that support it. to check if it is supported, you can use something like the modernizr javascript library. If it isn't, you can use a javascript fallback.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `onChange`:

```
 <INPUT NAME="dollar" SIZE=5 MAXLENGTH=5 onChange="this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '')">
```

Note: In FF3 at least it only runs after the value has been "confirmed", box lost focus or other and not instantaneously.

Comment: Sorry forgot the `this.value =` part somehow. Its fixed now.

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution (It also validates data copy&pasted):

```
function InputValidator(input, validationType, validChars) {
if (input === null || input.nodeType !== 1 || input.type !== 'text' && input.type !== 'number')
    throw ('Please specify a valid input');

if (!(InputValidator.ValidationType.hasOwnProperty(validationType) || validationType))
    throw 'Please specify a valid Validation type';

input.InputValidator = this;

input.InputValidator.ValidCodes = [];

input.InputValidator.ValidCodes.Add = function (item) {
    this[this.length] = item;
};

input.InputValidator.ValidCodes.hasValue = function (value, target) {
    var i;
    for (i = 0; i < this.length; i++) {
        if (typeof (target) === 'undefined') {
            if (this[i] === value)
                return true;
        }
        else {
            if (this[i][target] === value)
                return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
};

var commandKeys = {
    'backspace': 8,
    'tab': 9,
    'enter': 13,
    'shift': 16,
    'ctrl': 17,
    'alt': 18,
    'pause/break': 19,
    'caps lock': 20,
    'escape': 27,
    'page up': 33,
    'page down': 34,
    'end': 35,
    'home': 36,
    'left arrow': 37,
    'up arrow': 38,
    'right arrow': 39,
    'down arrow': 40,
    'insert': 45,
    'delete': 46,
    'left window key': 91,
    'right window key': 92,
    'select key': 93,
    /*creates Confusion in IE */
    //'f1': 112,
    //'f2': 113,
    //'f3': 114,
    //'f4': 115,
    //'f5': 116,
    //'f6': 117,
    //'f7': 118,
    //'f8': 119,
    //'f9': 120,
    //'f10': 121,
    //'f11': 122,
    //'f12': 123,
    'num lock': 144,
    'scroll lock': 145,
};

commandKeys.hasValue = function (value) {
    for (var a in this) {
        if (this[a] === value)
            return true;
    }

    return false;
};

function getCharCodes(arrTarget, chars) {
    for (var i = 0; i < chars.length; i++) {
        arrTarget.Add(chars[i].charCodeAt(0));
    }
}

function triggerEvent(name, element) {
    if (document.createEventObject) {
        // dispatch for IE
        var evt = document.createEventObject();
        return element.fireEvent('on' + name, evt)
    }
    else {
        // dispatch for firefox + others
        var evt = document.createEvent("HTMLEvents");
        evt.initEvent(name, true, true); // event type,bubbling,cancelable
        return !element.dispatchEvent(evt);
    }
}

if (validationType == InputValidator.ValidationType.Custom) {
    if (typeof (validChars) === 'undefined')
        throw 'Please add valid characters';

    getCharCodes(input.InputValidator.ValidCodes, validChars);
}
else if (validationType == InputValidator.ValidationType.Decimal) {
    getCharCodes(input.InputValidator.ValidCodes, '0123456789.');
}
else if (validationType == InputValidator.ValidationType.Numeric) {
    getCharCodes(input.InputValidator.ValidCodes, '0123456789');
}

input.InputValidator.ValidateChar = function (c) {
    return this.ValidCodes.hasValue(c.charCodeAt(0));
}

input.InputValidator.ValidateString = function (s) {
    var arr = s.split('');

    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
        if (!this.ValidateChar(arr[i])) {
            arr[i] = '';
        }
    }

    return arr.join('');
}

function bindEvent(el, eventName, eventHandler) {
    if (el.addEventListener) {
        el.addEventListener(eventName, eventHandler, false);
    } else if (el.attachEvent) {
        el.attachEvent('on' + eventName, eventHandler);
    }
}

function getCaretPosition(i) {
    if (!i) return;

    if ('selectionStart' in i) {
        return i.selectionStart;
    }
    else {
        if (document.selection) {
            var sel = document.selection.createRange();
            var selLen = document.selection.createRange().text.length;
            sel.moveStart('character', -i.value.length);
            return sel.text.length - selLen;
        }
    }
}

function setCursor(node, pos) {
    var node = (typeof (node) === "string" || node instanceof String) ? document.getElementById(node) : node;

    if (!node) {
        return false;
    }
    else if (node.createTextRange) {
        var textRange = node.createTextRange();
        textRange.collapse(true);
        textRange.moveEnd(pos);
        textRange.moveStart(pos);
        textRange.select();
        return true;
    } else if (node.setSelectionRange) {
        node.setSelectionRange(pos, pos);
        return true;
    }

    return false;
}

function validateActive() {
    if (input.isActive) {
        var pos = getCaretPosition(input);

        var arr = input.value.split('');

        for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
            if (!this.ValidateChar(arr[i])) {
                arr[i] = '';

                if (pos > i)
                    pos--;
            }
        }
        console.log('before : ' + input.value);

        input.value = arr.join('');
        console.log('after : ' + input.value, input);
        setCursor(input, pos);

        setTimeout(validateActive, 10);
    }
}

bindEvent(input, 'keypress', function (e) {
    var evt = e || window.event;
    var charCode = evt.which || evt.keyCode;

    if (!input.InputValidator.ValidCodes.hasValue(charCode) && !commandKeys.hasValue(charCode)) {
        if (evt.preventDefault) {
            evt.preventDefault();
            evt.stopPropagation();
        }
        return false;
    }
});

bindEvent(input, 'keyup', function (e) {
    var evt = e || window.event;
    var charCode = evt.which || evt.keyCode;

    if (!input.InputValidator.ValidCodes.hasValue(charCode) && !commandKeys.hasValue(charCode)) {
        if (evt.preventDefault) {
            evt.preventDefault();
            evt.stopPropagation();
        }
        return false;
    }
});

bindEvent(input, 'change', function (e) {
    var dt = input.value;

    input.value = input.InputValidator.ValidateString(input.value);

    if (input.value !== dt)
        triggerEvent('change', input);
});

bindEvent(input, 'blur', function (e) {
    var dt = input.value;
    input.value = input.InputValidator.ValidateString(input.value);

    input.isActive = false;

    if (input.value !== dt)
        triggerEvent('blur', input);
});

bindEvent(input, 'paste', function (e) {
    var evt = e || window.event;
    var svt = input.value;

    if (evt && evt.clipboardData && evt.clipboardData.getData) {// Webkit - get data from clipboard, put into editdiv, cleanup, then cancel event
        if (/text\/html/.test(evt.clipboardData.types)) {
            var dt = evt.clipboardData.getData('text/html');

            input.value = input.InputValidator.ValidateString(dt);
            if (input.value !== dt)
                triggerEvent('change', input);
        }
        else if (/text\/plain/.test(e.clipboardData.types)) {
            var dt = evt.clipboardData.getData('text/plain');

            input.value = input.InputValidator.ValidateString(dt);
            if (input.value !== dt)
                triggerEvent('change', input);
        }
        else {
            input.value = '';
        }
        waitforpastedata(input, svt);
        if (e.preventDefault) {
            e.stopPropagation();
            e.preventDefault();
        }
        return false;
    }
    else {// Everything else - empty editdiv and allow browser to paste content into it, then cleanup
        input.value = '';
        waitforpastedata(input, svt);
        return true;
    }
});

bindEvent(input, 'select', function (e) {
    var evt = e || window.event;

    if (evt.preventDefault) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        evt.stopPropagation();
    }
    return false;
});

bindEvent(input, 'selectstart', function (e) {
    var evt = e || window.event;

    if (evt.preventDefault) {
        evt.preventDefault();
        evt.stopPropagation();
    }
    return false;
});

/* no need to validate wile active,
   removing F keys fixed IE compatability*/
//bindEvent(input, 'fucus', function (e) {
//    input.isActive = true;
//    validateActive();
//});

//validate current value of the textbox
{
    var dt = input.value;
    input.value = input.InputValidator.ValidateString(input.value);

    //trigger event to indicate value has changed
    if (input.value !== dt)
        triggerEvent('change', input);
}

function waitforpastedata(elem, savedcontent) {
    if (elem.value !== '') {
        var dt = input.value;
        elem.value = elem.InputValidator.ValidateString(elem.value);

        if (input.value !== dt)
            triggerEvent('change', input);
    }
    else {
        var that = {
            e: elem,
            s: savedcontent
        }
        that.callself = function () {
            waitforpastedata(that.e, that.s)
        }
        setTimeout(that.callself, 10);
    }
}
}

InputValidator.ValidationType = new (function (types) {
    for (var i = 0; i < types.length; i++) {
        this[types[i]] = types[i];
    }
})(['Numeric', 'Custom', 'Decimal']);
```

To apply it to an input, do the following :

```
new InputValidator(document.getElementById('txtValidate'), InputValidator.ValidationType.Decimal);/* Numeric or Custom */
```

If you specify Custom as the validation type you have to specify the valid characters.
eg :

```
new InputValidator(document.getElementById('txtValidate'), InputValidator.ValidationType.Custom,'1234abc');
```